# image not picking up the path

Tags: php, mysql

this my code but unable to display image from db in php.i think this is not pick up the path.any one can help in this regard.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM info WHERE empid= '". $empid ."'");
$result->bindParam('. $empid .', $empid);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $rows = $result->fetch(); $i++){

    echo '<img src="images/".$row["image"]." ">';

    echo '<img src="images/".$row["image"]. > ' ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a closer look on $result->bindParam

Comment: what is the issue bro??

Comment: Take a look at [pdostatement.bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: its not working on it

Comment: It won't work as long as you don't fix the bindparam issue

Comment: PDO or Mysqli ?

Comment: how to fix it??could u help in this regard??

Comment: @bub how do i fix the issue??

Comment: @Anant both they are not working in my code

Comment: @Anant code is runing but image is not display

Comment: @Anant image icon is shown but img is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

You either concatenate the id onto the text string containing the query or use a parameter place holder and then bind a value to it. Not both, as you were doing.

The most secure way is to use parameters.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');


// I assume you have set $empid somewhere in the missing code here

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM info WHERE empid= :empid");
$result->bindParam(':empid', $empid, , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // also changed these 2 rows to correct the concatenation
    echo '<img src="images/"' . $row["image"] . '">';
    echo '<img src="images/"' . $row["image"] . '">';
}
?>
```